# Why does setting TextEditingController.text and TextEditingController.value yield different outputs?

Tags: flutter

**Minimum reproducible code:**

```dart
class SomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<SomePage> createState() => _SomePageState();
}

class _SomePageState extends State<SomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(() {
      final String currentText = _controller.text;
      print(currentText);
      if (currentText == 'foo') {
        _controller.text = 'bar'; // 1
        // _controller.value = _controller.value.copyWith(text: 'bar'); // 2
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Material(child: TextField(controller: _controller));
}
```

Using Option 1 (`_controller.text = 'bar';`), the output is:

```
f
fo
foo
bar
bar
```

Using Option 2 (`_controller.value = _controller.value.copyWith(text: 'bar');`), the output is:

```
f
fo
foo
bar
```

Why is there an extra `bar` printed when I use Option 1?

Comment: most likely this is because how `text` setter is implemented: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e1e47221e8/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/editable_text.dart#L224 - try `_controller.value.copyWith` the same way and check the results

Comment: @pskink I observed that removing `selection: const TextSelection.collapsed(offset: -1)` resolves the issue. I believe that setting text accomplishes two tasks: firstly, it sets the text which triggers the listener, and secondly, it positions the cursor at the start, also invoking the listener